# What is the meaning of cPanel permissions

Tags: linux, security, permissions, cpanel, shared-hosting

According to the following screen shot of cPanel change permissions for a directory on my shared Linux host:

[image]

As shown in the screen shot there are three values: **User**, **Group** and **World**. I want to know which of them is meant by the application, i.e Drupal, Joomla or any other PHP application that uses the server from my account. As I regarded before, it is on a shared environment, and as shown, it is a temporary directory, so I want to get sure that there is no any other user on the server could able to access that directory or even any of my directories available on my hosting account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are basic Linux Filesystem permittions

check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Comment: adding to your confusion. this is binds with the username on your system and not with the joomla/drupal.. I have 777 permissions on TMP but with No exec mount and other options. read this: http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/dedicated-server/securing-tmp-partition-cpanel-whm/

Comment: your directory is not possible to be accessed if the server is properly build. I do use Jailing for each user, so they cannot see the other's folders. And the permissions on each homedir are 711 (which is rwx --x --x)

Comment: What I mean, for example, such `tmp` directory is used by Drupal, does Drupal (or any web application on my host ) acting as World or Group or User? so if I remove write permissions for one of them which of them prevents the application to write on the directory?

Comment: if they use suphp, ohp is executed by the user/owner of the account. So it is the owner permissions